# Flutter Triangle Slider Track Shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to create a slider, like a volume in the windows control panel.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had found the solution by extending the SliderTrackShape Class and using the class in Slider Theme.

```
class TriangleTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {

@override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    SliderThemeData? sliderTheme,
    bool? isEnabled,
    bool? isDiscrete,
  }) {
    final double thumbWidth =
        sliderTheme!.thumbShape!.getPreferredSize(true, isDiscrete!).width;
    const double trackHeight = 2.0;
    assert(thumbWidth >= 0);
    assert(trackHeight >= 0);
    assert(parentBox.size.width >= thumbWidth);
    assert(parentBox.size.height >= trackHeight);

    final double trackLeft = offset.dx + thumbWidth / 2;
    final double trackTop =
        offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width - thumbWidth;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    SliderThemeData? sliderTheme,
    Animation<double>? enableAnimation,
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    Offset? thumbCenter,
    bool? isDiscrete,
    bool? isEnabled,
  }) {
    if (sliderTheme!.trackHeight == 0) {
      return;
    }

    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );
    // Paint color for active and inactive segments of the track. We can also define the colors to be gradient here.
    final Paint activePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.orange
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    final Paint inactivePaint = Paint()
      ..color = appLineColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    Paint leftTrackPaint = activePaint;
    Paint rightTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
    
   // For LTR/RTL support.
    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        leftTrackPaint = activePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        break;
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        leftTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = activePaint;
        break;
    }

    // Since the triangle resembles the right triangle find the y co-ordinate (height with respect to the selection value, so the path of active and inactive segements can be drawn)
    const double trackHeightVariation = 12;
    const double trackShiftAlongY = 6; // Shift the track so that the thumb will be placed in the center.
    final double trackDistance = (trackRect.right - trackRect.left).abs();
    final double customTrackHeight =
        (trackRect.bottom - (trackRect.top - trackHeightVariation));
    final valuePercent = ((thumbCenter!.dx - trackRect.left) / 1).abs();
    final yPoint = ((customTrackHeight / trackDistance) * valuePercent);

    final activePathSegment = Path()
      ..moveTo(trackRect.left, trackRect.bottom + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..lineTo(trackRect.left, trackRect.top + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..lineTo(thumbCenter.dx, trackRect.top - yPoint + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..lineTo(thumbCenter.dx, trackRect.bottom + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..close();

    final inactivePathSegment = Path()
      ..moveTo(thumbCenter.dx, trackRect.bottom + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..lineTo(thumbCenter.dx, trackRect.top - yPoint + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..lineTo(trackRect.right,
          trackRect.top - trackHeightVariation + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..lineTo(trackRect.right, trackRect.bottom + trackShiftAlongY)
      ..close();

    context.canvas.drawPath(activePathSegment, leftTrackPaint);
    context.canvas.drawPath(inactivePathSegment, rightTrackPaint);
    // If we want shadows to the track or active portion we can define that and draw that.
  }
}
```

Comment: this answer is very useful, but the thumb is not center to the track.

Comment: I got desired output. You try to play with this especially with trackShiftAlongY

Comment: could you please post your code here.?

Comment: the above is my code